# Calling Authorized Route in Postman OK, but Unauthorized from Console Client App

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0

Just fiddling around with IdentityServer4 in my .net core 3.1 project.

Been following this quickstart :http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html

If I debug the console app, copy the token in Postman and call a route with that require authorize on my api, I get the data back (and unauthorized if I leave out the token)

However if I debug on, I get a 401 in the console app when requesting the route.

Any obvious reason?

Comment: Have you verified that you get metadata from discovery endpoint? And the tokenReponse, is the access token inside?

Comment: Yes to both.  Got the metadata at http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration and actually copied the token from  the response  while debugging and used it in postman.

Comment: I know it's obvious, but ... are you adding the token to the request?client.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

Comment: What do you mean by 'if I debug on'? How much longer do you wait to do the second request after the first one? All access tokens have an expiration so maybe your token expired?